# How can I get TeamCity to check out SVN externals?

Tags: svn, teamcity, svn-externals

I have a project which TeamCity is downloading from SVN to build.  The problem is that I have some externals in the project which SVN does not download and therefore the build fails.  is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is built in functionality. http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Subversion